# Closing database connections on Heroku

Tags: postgresql, go, heroku

The hobby-tier PostgreSQL database comes with at most 20 connections and because of that, I implemented a little trigger to close the connections with the database as soon as the connection quota is hit.

The quota I established is 10 and on the local machine which `heroku local` it works perfectly but on the Heroku server it doesn't close the used connections. Worth to mention I implemented a `stats` page containing the number of open connections (using the `sql.DB.Stats().InUse`) used by the `*sql.DB` of the application (which is implemented as a singleton) and the page shows the number of open connections after a single usage which is less than what is shown in the Heroku database status page.

The trigger aforementioned is implemented whenever the application requests a connection and is implemented as the following:

```
func GetConnection() *sql.Conn {
    // The connect just opens a connection with the database returning a valid *sql.DB
    if Database == nil {
        Connect()
    }

    if Database.Stats().InUse >= 10 {
        Database.Close()
        // Seems like Java but I just wanted to be sure on Heroku
        Database = nil
        Connect()
    }

    ctx, _ := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), time.Second*10)

    conn, err := Database.Conn(ctx)

    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Couldn't get a connection from the pool. Reason %v", err)
    }

    return conn
}
```

As you can see I even implemented a context with a timeout of 10 seconds to automatically cancel the established connection, but it doesn't seem to work as well.

- I tried to use `pgbouncer` but both on my local machine and the Heroku server it doesn't seem to work as well.
- Another thing I tried is to `defer c.Close()` the connection received from `GetConnection()` but that stalls the application.
- Tried to use `sql.DB.SetMaxOpenConns(...)` but it doesn't work as well as explained in the comments.

Comment: Have you taken a look at [```DB.SetMaxOpenConns```](https://golang.org/pkg/database/sql/#DB.SetMaxOpenConns)?

Comment: Sure, I just forgot to say that as well in the question. Doesn't work as no connection is freed after the database reaches the previously set max open connections.

Comment: OK then use ```db.SetMaxIdleConns``` as well (so idle connections are freed up - default is 2 but you can set it to 0 if thats what you need).

Comment: It doesn't work @Brits.

Comment: What part is not working? [Here](https://play.golang.org/p/BXbg2Uy5W73) is a quick test I threw together which indicates this works OK on my setup (additional connections are closed immediatly) - perhaps try running this against your db and see what happens? Note: It's unclear from your example whether you are closing the connections or not (you need to close them!) - one other question; are you isong goroutines? (```GetConnection()``` is not currently goroutine-safe)

Comment: The part on the Heroku server. On a local database that works just fine @Brits. Aside from that, I'm not using goroutines and GetConnection() is called every time I have to use the database to query or to execute something and then the Database is recreated at every 10 connections (I know it is quite expensive).

Comment: I'm not sure the problem is clear. What I meant is: on Heroku the connections are not closed as implemented by the code which shows that for every ten connections the database connection is reestablished.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207792/discussion-between-brits-and-ranu).